# Chrome not receiving fcm messages, but firefox does

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to facilitate push messages in a custom service worker.  I followed the FCM getting started but am running into issues where the javascript client isn't receiving the sent messages on chrome, but firefox is working as intended.

The messages are being sent from a hosted server, and the messages are sent with no failures and message id's associated with each registered client.

Below is the page script and below that will be relevant service worker code.

**page html**

```
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        <CONFIG SETTINGS>
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();
</script>
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function (registration) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
                resetUI();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
            });
        });
    }
    const permissionDivId = 'permission_div';
    messaging.onTokenRefresh(function () {
        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (refreshedToken) {
                console.log('Token refreshed.');
                setTokenSentToServer(false);
                sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
                resetUI();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
            });
    });
    messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        appendMessage(payload);
    });
    function resetUI() {
        clearMessages();
        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (currentToken) {
                if (currentToken) {
                    sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                    updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
                } else {
                    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
                    setTokenSentToServer(false);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                setTokenSentToServer(false);
            });
    }
    function sendTokenToServer(currentToken) {
        if (!isTokenSentToServer()) {
            console.log('Sending token to server...');
            <TOKEN SENT TO SERVER AND STORED>
            setTokenSentToServer(true);
        } else {
            console.log('Token already sent to server so won\'t send it again ' +
                'unless it changes');
        }
    }
    function isTokenSentToServer() {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('sentToServer') == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function setTokenSentToServer(sent) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('sentToServer', sent ? 1 : 0);
    }
    function showHideDiv(divId, show) {
        const div = document.querySelector('#' + divId);
        if (show) {
            div.style = "display: visible";
        } else {
            div.style = "display: none";
        }
    }
    function requestPermission() {
        console.log('Requesting permission...');
        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                resetUI();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
            });
    }
    function deleteToken() {
        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (currentToken) {
                messaging.deleteToken(currentToken)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log('Token deleted.');
                        setTokenSentToServer(false);
                        resetUI();
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log('Unable to delete token. ', err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
            });
    }
    // Add a message to the messages element.
    function appendMessage(payload) {
        const messagesElement = document.querySelector('#messages');
        const dataHeaderELement = document.createElement('h5');
        const dataElement = document.createElement('pre');
        dataElement.style = 'overflow-x:hidden;'
        dataHeaderELement.textContent = 'Received message:';
        dataElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
        messagesElement.appendChild(dataHeaderELement);
        messagesElement.appendChild(dataElement);
    }
    // Clear the messages element of all children.
    function clearMessages() {
        const messagesElement = document.querySelector('#messages');
        while (messagesElement.hasChildNodes()) {
            messagesElement.removeChild(messagesElement.lastChild);
        }
    }
    function updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken) {
        showHideDiv(permissionDivId, false);
    }
    function updateUIForPushPermissionRequired() {
        showHideDiv(permissionDivId, true);
    }
</script>
```

**sw.js**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  console.log('Service Worker recived a push message', event.data.text());
  var notification = event.data.json().notification;
  var title = notification.title;
  event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(title, {
          body: notification.body,
          icon: notification.icon,
          data: { url: notification.click_action }
      }));
});
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Service workers require secure origins to ensure that the service worker script is from the intended origin and hasn't come about from a man-in-the-middle attack. Currently, that means using HTTPS on live sites, though localhost will work during development.

Are you using localhos or an https url?

Comment: I am not using localhost, but a custom host name and a signed cert for hosting over https on my local dev server.  The service worker is registered and working correctly as I am using it for other things like caching and PWA's.

Comment: Are the notifications allowed in the site configuration? https://www.dropbox.com/s/rojk62s19lpes42/push%20notifications.png?dl=0

Comment: Notifications are allowed, and I have a button toggle to revoke access and resubmit the request. This process also will resend the device id to the server to store for sending the notification.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The `messaging.onMessage(...)` isn't receiving any message. @diswimmer, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Similar issue, but with service workers -> everything works well on client browser Firefox and Chrome, and on SW on Firefox, but somehow the Chrome SW does not fire and show nothing in it's console...